# Scala map function to remove fields

Tags: scala, function, lambda, functional-programming

I have a list of Person objects with many fields and I can easily do:

```
list.map(person => person.getName)
```

In order to generate another collection with all the peoples names.

How can you use the map function to create a new collection with all the fields of the Person class, BUT their name though?

In other words, how can you create a new collection out of a given collection which will contain all the elements of your initial collection with some of their fields removed?

Comment: Your question is not really well defined. I'm guessing you have a bunch of "getter" functions, and you want something like `list.map(person => Seq(person.getHeight, person.getWeight))`. In order to do that, Scala would have to know which functions are "getter" functions. You certainly could do that by maintaining a list of "getter" functions in your `Person` class and filtering out `getName` from that list, but that gets tedious to maintain. Also worth noting that Scala style typically avoids getters and setters in favor of immutable variables. Can you describe why you want to do this?

Comment: In my case the Person object is actually an immutable Java object with many getters - I thought of using some reflection to retrieve all its methods and then filtering them out, but that is too tedious indeed. I can also use the map function to specify which getter methods I would like to map to, but in case you have more getters to map than to exclude, that may get tedious too. I was hoping scala could provide some one-line magic that can be used in such cases.

Comment: You could extend the `Person` class to create a `Map` of fields, which you could then easily filter. `implicit class extendPerson(p: Person) { def getAllFields: Map[String, String] = Map("name" -> p.getName, "age" ->p.getAge, ...)` and then `person.getAllFields.filterKeys(k => k != "name")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `unapply` method of your `case class` to extract the members as `tuple` then remove the things that you don't want from the `tuple`.

```
case class Person(name: String, Age: Int, country: String)
// defined class Person

val personList = List(
  Person("person_1", 20, "country_1"),
  Person("person_2", 30, "country_2")
)
// personList: List[Person] = List(Person(person_1,20,country_1), Person(person_2,30,country_2))

val tupleList = personList.flatMap(person => Person.unapply(person))
// tupleList: List[(String, Int, String)] = List((person_1,20,country_1), (person_2,30,country_2))

val wantedTupleList = tupleList.map({ case (name, age, country) => (age, country) })
// wantedTupleList: List[(Int, String)] = List((20,country_1), (30,country_2))

// the above is more easy to understand but will cause two parses of list
// better is to do it in one parse only, like following

val yourList = personList.flatMap(person => {
  Person.unapply(person) match {
    case (name, age, country) => (age, country)
  }
})
// yourList: List[(Int, String)] = List((20,country_1), (30,country_2))
```

Comment: The single parse can be simplified: `map{case Person(_, age, country) => (age, country)}`